# PHP - avoid duplication in viewing DB data

Tags: php, oop

A very theoretical question - how do you people avoid code duplication in displaying DB data in a case where you have few queries that all return slightly different set of data from the same table?

I'm racking my brain how to minimize the effort of displaying these records - currently I have a `switch` construct which based on the type of query builds the table. In my eyes this is very ineffective - are there any other ways that come to your minds?

Results are fetched via PDO using the fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS) - results are fetched into object. This object has private properties that match the columns returned by the query and methods that return these private properties.

```
switch($result)
case "a":
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
 echo "<tr><td>".$row->getId()."</td></tr>";
 }
case "b":
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
 echo "<tr><td>".$row->getId()."</td></tr>";
 }
 ...
```

EDIT:
I realize the information here is bit vague and general so I'll try to expand it a little.
Scenario A: 'return all records'
Scenario B: 'return records that meet condition, do not include columns x, y, z'

Both scenarios return very similar set of data but displaying them in HTML table requires a lot of code duplication (see code sample above).

Comment: Very obscure question too, could you maybe try to add in a real case scenario ? Because for now the switch makes no sense, indeed.

Comment: It seems to me, the answer you're looking for is: Put your whatever in a function and call it passing `all return slightly different set of data` - The question is too abstract to answer as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could maybe be a good starting point for you.
I did not bother to make a MySQL connection since you stated you use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` and methods to access private properties, I only got myself two objects to test this.

**GenericObject.php** - an abstract class allowing me to get columns readable headers, get a list of properties of an object and get the associated values of those properties.

```
<?php

abstract class GenericObject extends stdClass{

    public function translateColumn($column){
        return isset($this->_columnsNames[$column]) ?
            $this->_columnsNames[$column] :
            $column;
    }

    public function __get($name){
        /**
         * I used a magic getter for ease of use, but if you have getters
         * like getSomething, that could also work, see note on getColumns()
         */
        return $this->{$name};
    }

    public function getColumns(){
        /**
         * This is only for ease of use, since I only write a magic getter.
         * Alternatively you can use get_class_methods($this) and
         * filter only on methods beginning with get like getSomething,
         * this way you can list all your getters and all your properties
         */
        return array_keys($this->_columnsNames);
    }
}
```

**A.php** a dummy example class inheriting GenericObject

```
<?php

class A extends GenericObject{
    protected $a = "a";
    protected $b = "b";
    protected $c = "c";

    protected $_columnsNames = array(
        "a" => "Column A",
        "b" => "Column B",
        "c" => "Column C",
    );
}
```

**B.php** another dummy example class inheriting GenericObject, with different properties than class A

```
<?php

class B extends GenericObject{
    protected $a = "a";
    protected $c = "c";
    protected $d = "d";
    protected $e = "e";
    protected $f = "f";

    protected $_columnsNames = array(
        "a" => "Column A",
        "c" => "Column C",
        "d" => "Column D",
        "e" => "Column E",
        "f" => "Column F",
    );
}
```

**TableHelper.php** our table helper, that draw a table and its headers based on the objects properties

```
<?php

class TableHelper{
    public function drawTable(array $ar){
        $html = '';
        if(count($ar) > 0){
            foreach($ar as $elem){
                if($html == ''){
                    $tHead = $this->drawHeader($elem);
                }
                $html .= $this->drawLine($elem);
            }
            $html = <<<HTML
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        {$tHead}
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {$html}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
HTML;
        }
        return $html;
    }

    protected function drawLine(stdClass $obj){
        $row = '';
        $vars = $obj->getColumns();
        foreach($vars as $column){
            $value = $obj->$column;
            $row .= <<<HTML
                <td>{$value}</td>
HTML;
        }
        return <<<HTML
                <tr>{$row}</tr>
HTML;
    }

    protected function drawHeader(stdClass $obj){
        $tHead = '';
        $vars = $obj->getColumns();
        foreach($vars as $column){
            /**
             * This is only a suggestion of a way to translate columns names
             */
            $column = $obj->translateColumn($column);
            $tHead .= <<<HTML
                <th>{$column}</th>
HTML;
        }
        return <<<HTML
                <tr>{$tHead}</tr>
HTML;
    }
}
```

**Basic usage of all those :**

```
<?php
    $table = new TableHelper();
    echo $table->drawTable(
        array(
            new A(),
            new A(),
            new A(),
        )
    );
?>
<br/><br/>
<?php
    echo $table->drawTable(
        array(
            new B(),
            new B(),
            new B(),
            new B(),
        )
    );
?>
```

**And last be not least, what it does outputs** (where you can actually see I'm more a developer than I'm a designer, obviously).

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
      <th>Column C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br/><br/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column C</th>
      <th>Column D</th>
      <th>Column E</th>
      <th>Column F</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
      <td>f</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return same set of data in Your query, for example:

```
SELECT price as value_to_display FROM prices;
SELECT name as value_to_display FROM persons;
```

Or even use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html), to merge query results into one query.

```
(SELECT price as value_to_display FROM prices)
UNION
(SELECT name as value_to_display FROM persons);
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumming your results are valid, and using mysqli basically when you get your results:

```
    while ($data = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        //Now every record you have is now an array. Do with what you want. 
        echo $data['username']; // This will output the column 'username' from your record.
    }
```

in my opinion, using a `foreach` is a bit of a mess unless you plan on displaying everything at once and not process any information from the record.